# Index of a variable in a number list in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, variables

I want to find the index of a variable in a number list.

My code is this:

```py
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    x = 8
    a=x
    while x == a:
        b = len(arr)//2
        if arr[b]==x:
    # find the index of x variable
```

Comment: Use `arr.index(x)`

Comment: @Sociopath No it do not work I tried for it

Comment: @Greg the variable should change

Comment: In [14]: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].index(8)
Out[14]: 7

Comment: @SamsuIslam can you expalin

Comment: @Greg I want index not value

Comment: The index() method searches an element in the list and returns its position/index of fist occurrence.

Comment: The canonical way to get an index is the ``index`` method. If you get an error using this, please provide a [mcve] to debug this. If you do not want to use the ``index`` method, please clearly state the restrictions for this task.

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) since your list is sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem achieved by the linear search algorithm:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x=8
flag = False
index = None
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == x:
        flag = True
        index = i


if not flag:
    print("Number is not present in list.")
else:
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the index of a variable in a number list, you can directly use the built-in method of python that is `index`. It gives `ValueError` if the number is not present in the list.

```
try:
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    x=8
    print(arr.index(x))
except ValueError:
    print("Number is not present in list.")
```

Comment: Then, you can use any of the searching algorithms.